# Android - why setVisibility doesn't work?

Tags: android, visibility, android-imageview

I have a ToggleButton which when pressed, it hides/shows an ImageView:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    View view = (View) v.getTag();

    ImageView messageStatusImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.messageStatusImageView);

    if (((CheckableLinearLayout)v).isChecked()) {
           messageStatusImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
           messageStatusImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

The problem is the ImageView is not becoming `VISIBLE` again.

Does someone knows why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your `CheckableLinearLayout` is always checked so else condition never be applied. Check it out and look where you are changing checked property(if do).

Comment: `View.GONE` removes the `View` from the layout. Use `View.INVISIBLE` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Sajmon, it was something like that! :-)

Comment: Squonk, please post your comment as an answer so this question can have an accepted answer.